# Vf Page Using datepicker JS calender

Tags: visualforce, javascript-controller

VF Page-

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="Test4">
    <apex:stylesheet value="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"  />
    <apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" />
    <apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" />
    <script>
        $(function aaa(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});
    });
    </script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="changeDate" action="{!changeDateRange}" reRender="Date1" status="myStatus">
        <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!selectId}" value="" />
        <apex:param name="secondParam" assignTo="{!myDate}" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>

        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectId}" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!displayOptions}"></apex:selectOptions>
            </apex:selectList>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function callActionMethod()
{
 var txtVal1 = $(function aaa(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 10});
    });
 var txtVal2 = $(function aaa(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 20});
    });
 changeDate(txtVal1,txtVal2);
}
</script>
</apex:page>
```

---

Controller

```
public class Test4 {

    public List<selectoption> displayOptions { get; set; }
    public String selectId { get; set; }
    public Date myDate {get;set;}

    public test4()
    {
        myDate = Date.today();
        displayOptions =new List<selectoption>();
        displayOptions.add(new selectoption('none','-select-'));
        displayOptions.add(new selectoption('10','Next 10 Days'));
        displayOptions.add(new selectoption('20','Next 20 Days'));
    }

    public PageReference changeDateRange() {
        myDate = Date.today();
        if(selectId.equals('10')){
            myDate = myDate.addDays(10);
        } else if(selectId.equals('20')){
            myDate = myDate.addDays(20);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have one dropdown  and one calender 
In DropDown- 1-Next 10 Days
                     2-Next 20 Days
when i select next 10 days calender start from next 10 days date and before this date all dates are disabled

example--today date is 6/20/2017   if i select next 10 days then date start from 6/30/2017 and before this all dates are disabled same as next 20 days.

Comment: what is the exact issue you are facing in this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable and enable the dates by using the methods of datepicker plugin. There are multiple utility methods available in the library which you can use.